# can logback use property defined in spring?

Tags: spring, properties, logback

we put properties in a specific place(kept by zooKeeper, and already parsed into spring), not in classpath. Now in logback.xml, I need a DBAppender to log messages into mysql, I don't want to copy a properties into classpath, and I try to use placeholder `${url}` directly without importing properties in logback.xml, it does not work.

So is there a way to use configuration in spring for logback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No logback can only access system properties. And also logback tends to be intialised before spring, although you can cause it to be reconfigured.

Have a look at how spring-boot does it. It copies some (about 3 or 4) properties from spring config into system properties before re-initialising logback. In this way the log file path can be interpolated via spring properties and variable replacement.